# Перегрузка методов в C# с помощью ref

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, методы

Ни как не могу понять в [книге](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24763888/) написано, что перегрузка методов невозможно с помощь `ref`

[image: Книжка]

Хотя у меня это получилось

```
Another an = new Another();
int a = 0;

an.SomeMethod(a);
an.SomeMethod(ref a);

class Another
{
    public void SomeMethod(int a)
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    public void SomeMethod(ref int a)
    {
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

Может быть что то не так понял ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно, это не самый хороший перевод. Запрещена на самом деле вот такая ситуация:

```
class Another
{
    public void SomeMethod(out int a)
    {
        a = 1;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(ref int a)
    {
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

Это производит ошибку [CS0063](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyfs0yyd.aspx):

> Cannot define overloaded methods that differ only on ref and out.

---

Причина состоит в том, что на уровне CLR `out` не существует, и кодируется как `ref`. Поэтому если бы это было разрешено, с точки зрения CLR это были бы две одинаковые сигнатуры. Отличие `out` от `ref` (то есть, то, что `out`-параметр обязательно должен быть инициализирован внутри метода) — внутреннее правило C#, CLR это не проверяет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Приятно видеть правильный и развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Евгений: Пожалуйста!